# command in buildah equivalent docker import

Tags: docker, containers, buildah

Does exist a command in buildah to achieve the same result of docker import?
I need to get the same result of

```
docker import output/images/rootfs.tar <myproject:mytag>
```

with buidah.

Thanks.